# Wordpress removing slashes from shortcode output

Tags: filters, shortcode

I've got a problem, what I'm trying to do is passing a url through a shortcode and use it as a background image, the problem is that the url gets processed and all the slashes gets removed. I tried removing the wordpress filter `remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );`) but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Here's my code:

```
function section_shortcode_func( $atts, $content = null ){
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        [
        'bgimage' => '',
        ], $atts, 'section'
    );
    $return = '<div class="section" style="background-image: url("'. $atts['bgimage'] .'")">';  
}
```

Comment: How do you call the shortcode? Are you sure it doesn't get removed before the shortcode gets called (try `str_replace("/","_", $atts["bgimage"])` to see if slashes were present)?

Comment: [section bgimage="http://xxx.xxx/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/xxx.jpg"] I'm sure the link it's not filtered before the shortcode call because I did a vardump and the link it's fine. I just tried str_replace and yes it works.

Comment: the code you put in the question do nothing, edit your question to show the code you use

Answer (score 1):

Here is the correct shortcode function

```
function section_shortcode_func( $atts, $content = null ){

    $atts       = shortcode_atts( array( 'bgimage' => '' ), $atts);
    $bgimage    = isset( $atts['bgimage'] ) ? $atts['bgimage'] : '';

    ob_start();
    echo "<div class='section' style='background-image: url($bgimage)'>";  
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Now you can call it this way

```
[section bgimage="xxx.xxx/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/xxx.jpg"]
```

Comment: @Dave If not worked this, then let me know, Thanks

Comment: Jaed Mosharraf, a shortcode function must return is content and not echoing it

Comment: Ops My mistakes

Correcting

Comment: @mmm Now it's ok?

Comment: You are always welcome :)